# Adding functions to HtmlWeb class

Tags: c#, class, html-agility-pack

I would like to add some functions to the HtmlWeb class, specifically these:

```
public HtmlDocument SubmitFormValues (NameValueCollection fv, string url)
{
    // Attach a temporary delegate to handle attaching
    // the post back data
    PreRequestHandler handler = delegate(HttpWebRequest request) {
        string payload = this.AssemblePostPayload (fv);
            byte[] buff = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (payload.ToCharArray ());
            request.ContentLength = buff.Length;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            System.IO.Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
            reqStream.Write (buff, 0, buff.Length);
            return true;
    }
    this.PreRequest += handler;
    HtmlDocument doc = this.Load (url, "POST");
    this.PreRequest -= handler;
    return doc;
}

private string AssemblePostPayload (NameValueCollection fv)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
    foreach (String key in fv.AllKeys) {
        sb.Append ("&" + key + "=" + fv.Get (key));
    }
    return sb.ToString ().Substring (1);
}
```

These functions are used to POST data to a website and then get the response html.

I've been having some difficulties with adding these functions and I want to know how to do it correctly.

The function would be used like this:

```
HtmlWeb webGet = new HtmlWeb();
NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection (1);
postData.Add ("name", "value");
string url = "url";
HtmlDocument doc = webGet.SubmitFormValues (postData, url);
```

Comment: I don't think the spaces would produce an error, but it can be a bit misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your methods are correct, you can create your own class inheriting `HtmlWeb` and put the 2 methods there :

```
public class HtmlWebExtended : HtmlWeb
{
    public HtmlDocument SubmitFormValues(NameValueCollection fv, string url)
    {
        // Attach a temporary delegate to handle attaching
        // the post back data
        ......
    }

    private string AssemblePostPayload(NameValueCollection fv)
    {
        ......
    }
}
```

Then use your own `HtmlWebExtended` class instead of the predefined `HtmlWeb` :

```
HtmlWebExtended webGet = new HtmlWebExtended();
NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection (1);
postData.Add("name", "value");
string url = "url";
HtmlDocument doc = webGet.SubmitFormValues(postData, url);
```